# Cubic formula derivation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

François Viète used the substitution $y=z-\frac{p}{3z}$ to transform the depressed cubic $y^3+py=q$ into an 'almost' quadratic equation.

$$\left(z-\frac{p}{3z}\right)^3+p\left(z-\frac{p}{3z}\right)+q=0$$
$$z^6+qz^3-\frac{p^3}{27}=0$$
$$z^3=\frac{-q+\sqrt{q^2+\frac{4p^3}{27}}}{2}=-\frac{q}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{q^2}{4}+\frac{p^3}{27}}$$
Now $$y=\sqrt[3]{-\frac{q}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{q^2}{4}+\frac{p^3}{27}}}-\frac{p}{3\sqrt[3]{-\frac{q}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{q^2}{4}+\frac{p^3}{27}}}}$$
but shouldn't this complicated looking fraction expression be equal to 
$$\sqrt[3]{\frac{q}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{q^2}{4}+\frac{p^3}{27}}}-\sqrt[3]{-\frac{q}{2}+\sqrt{\frac{q^2}{4}+\frac{p^3}{27}}}$$
the solution to the cubic derived from Cardano's geometric methods?

Also, why shouldn't we also take into account the negative solution in the quadratic formula? Didn't Viète and Cardano do this?

Thanks in advance for clearifying this. :)

Comment: Denote the cube root in the denominator of the second term in y as D(p,q). What do you get if you multiply the numerator and denominator of that term by D(p,-q)?

Comment: @CountIblis thanks so much! I get it now :)

Comment: see also here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicEquation.html